# Rectify Vector Features to Oblique/Isometric Raster

Tags: vector, orthorectification

I have a task which I would like to accomplish by overlaying a vector on to a raster, but the raster is oblique/non aerial. I have all the information that would be necessary to photogrametrically compute the vectors into the raster as cells, but what I think I'm looking for is something that can distort the vector to overlay the ground features in the image from the raster perspective (less computationally intensive).

For example, if I have a street level raster with two lampposts in it and a "aerial" vector of city underground electrical, I'm trying to skew the vector visualization to match the nodes in the network which are the connection points at the lamppost bases from the perspective of the raster so that the vector lines are visible "underground" on the raster connecting properly to the bases of the posts (ignoring issues that arise with overlapping 3d features from a 2d perspective).

I'm sure there is a toolset or process to describe this, but I don't seem to be able to find a name for it. Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as what this might be called and if there are any tools already existing that could accomplish this? Or am I overthinking the process and is this accomplishable with standard geo-rectification tools just in reverse? (not especially constrained by software/methodology).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this is called 'monoplotting', and some tools for doing it can be found on the [WSL website](http://www.wsl.ch/fe/oekosystem/insubrisch/projekte/Evoluzione_paesaggio/index_EN) or with a QGIS plugin called [Pic2Map](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Pic2Map/).